# Installation of Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10

Tags: boot

I have installed Windows 10 and then Ubuntu 18.04, I can see grub and able to choose between the OS's.

Later after somedays, I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 First and then Windows 10, this time system is directly booting to windows 10. But i observed that my linux partitions are there and all data is available. Only thing is it is not showing grub, booting directly to Windows. How can i resolve this. I prefer not to install any software or using shift key all the time to select between OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate your grub.

1. boot from live-CD
2. mount your filesystems from your original installation
   e. g.

   sudo mount /dev/sda<#> /mnt
3. chroot

   sudo chroot /mnt
4. recreate grub

   sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda

If you are using LVM you have to mount /dev/mapper/ /mnt

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226169/chroot-copy-or-mount-bind

Comment: @Wigalf Pimwick Thanks for the response. /dev/sda# this # is the number of EFI partition which I created when installing Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: /dev/sda# is the partition with your root-filesystem. You may check this with fdisk -l /dev/sda

Comment: have a look at sudo fdisk -l Gerät      Boot     Start       Ende  Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/sda1            2048  528533503 528531456   252G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       999088128 1000214527   1126400   550M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3  *    528533504  529582079   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda4       529584128  999088127 469504000 223,9G 8e Linux LVM