# Dual boot Windows, with Ubuntu first

Tags: windows

I currently have only Ubuntu stored on my new SSD, and am looking to add a dual boot to Windows 10.

However, I can't find much online explaining how to do so when Ubuntu was first. I don't really want to go through the hassle of uninstalling Ubuntu, installing Win10, and then reinstalling Ubuntu.

Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: I had asked the same question and got the answer. please go through this link.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042813/installation-of-windows-10-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-18-04-windows-10

Comment: UEFI or BIOS boot, most now are UEFI. If UEFI you should be be able to install Windows, and use efibootmgr to set Ubuntu as first in boot order. `sudo efibootmgr -v` & then set order with efibootmgr. see also 
`man efibootmgr` &  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Answer (score 0):

you can use **EasyBCD**

after installing windows, install EasyBCD application
at new entry tab, add grub2 and chooses ubuntu partition

Download link: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/